# Memory consumption for micronaut microservices

Tags: java, performance, microservices, micronaut

I have a question about performance. I have built some microservices cloud-oriented with micronaut. I deploy those services in Kubernetes and the performance is like:

- CPU: super good, they barely do not consume CPU
- RAM: They consume starting from 250MiB

As a first thought, 250MiB seems like too much for me when I read that micronaut is low memory-footprint.

So, the question is: Is it normal that my micronaut microservices consume, at least, 250MiB?

Just to give you an overview, my services wait for incoming requests and, even when they're doing "nothing", the memory consumed is more that 250MiB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal that my micronaut microservices consume, at least,
>   250MiB?

No.  I have seen many Micronaut services and I have seen zero that require at least 250MiB.

Comment: I've found this article https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2019/04/09/performance-comparison-between-spring-boot-and-micronaut/ where we can see that the microservice, just when it starts, allocates ~250MB for memory, which matches with my case.

Comment: It depends much on the JVM and the flags you pass to it. Using the right flags and for example OpenJ9 Micronaut can consume as little as 80MB of memory. Again it depends a lot on what the Microservice is doing

Comment: @Lobo Are you talking about JVM heap or total process memory?

Comment: @GraemeRocher I'm not setting any flag to run my microservice

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Since that value comes from Kubernetes, I guess is "total process memory", but not sure.